# Getting the primary constructor of a C# record

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, record

Consider the following C# record, which has one primary constructor and one secondary constructor:

```cs
record Foo(string Text, int Number)
{
    public Foo() : this(string.Empty, default)
    {
    }
}
```

Getting its constructors can be achieved like so:

```cs
ConstructorInfo[] constructors = typeof(Foo).GetConstructors();
```

Is there a way to determine which constructor is the primary constructor?

Comment: `Primary constructor` is a C# feature. In the .NET classes all constructors should appear the same

Comment: See [the decompiled C# code on sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUATgUwMYHs4BMAEAxFKAUIEADJgCoIAeALgDSYCWAdtZgHICuAtgEYJwBKWAG9YmcZhABmHHnwDMALkzUAFgwDOhEgDoAolwAO1AJ710CAGYBDDgBtqQmBMyjnEgL6wPQA). There is no attributes or anything like that on the primary constructor to differentiate it from any other constructor you declare, so the answer is probably a no.

Comment: Even if there was some sort of trick/pattern/heuristic you could apply to detect it, there's certainly nothing guaranteed, so if you truly have a need to detect this sort of thing it should probably only be done at compile time, using Roslyn. Note that you could choose to define something like "the single constructor that contains one argument for every public property of the class, with the types in the correct order" as your idea of a "primary constructor". This works regardless of language, but such a thing remains fragile; scenarios where it fails are not hard to imagine.

Comment: Fragility example: .NET Core's DI middleware uses the constructor with the most arguments, which leads to problems if that constructor accepts strings or other non-DI types